# Check if IFrame is Embeded on another site

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I know about `document.referrer` and `window.location` however I would like to find out in this example if `http://somesite.com/page` (url src in iframe) would either `console.log` or `document.body.innerHTML` to tell the user on `http://whatever.com/`

> "iFrame is on another site"

or

> "iFrame is on the main domain"

Is this at all possible in JavaScript?

Comment: i dont get what you aim to do here...?

Comment: I revised the question

Comment: so you may iframe things in your website from the same domain and if its from the same domain you want to output some text saying its from the same domain.. if it is not you want to output text saying it is not in the main domain? and you don't want to use document.referrer ? is this messaging populating on the main domain as well?

Comment: Not exactly I'm working on a coding playground and I want to change the way the UI is designed if the site is embedded in an iFrame on another site vs if it's on the main domain. - http://jsbin.com/toxofajibo/edit?html,output

Comment: Well then you could simply use a GET parameter/query string in the iframe source when you embed it on your own site to determine this – and the code you give the users to embed it into their own pages does not contain that parameter. (Of course this doesn’t prevent anyone from appending that parameter on their own, once they find it in the source code of your site – but since this is merely about a different UI, that should not have any serious implications.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what I want to do is not possible because of the the [Same Origin Policy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) :(

Answer (score 0):

I think a recursive function can be useful. If the framed page is cotrolled by you  something like this can work.

Create an element inside it and make id attribute `mycontrolelemet`

Then

```
function controller(element)
{
   if( element. nodeName == 'iframe' )
      {
          alert("it is a frame");
      }
    else
      {       
           controller(elemet.parentNode);
       }
}

controller(document.getElementById("mycontrolelemet").parentNode);
```